# Why isn't the ClientIDMode being honored here?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-2.0

I have an ASP.NET 2.0 web application, and on one of the pages I have a `div` defined like this:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAddJobCode" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Static">
```

and it's inside of a content placeholder defined like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainBodyContent" runat="server">
```

but when the HTML is generated I get a name like this `ctl00_MainBodyContent_pnlAddJobCode` so clearly it's not honoring the `ClientIDMode`. The problem is I need to set some styles on this specific `div` -how can I get the `ClientIDMode` to work here?

Does `ClientIDMode` **not work** in ASP.NET 2.0? I have found a few articles on Google that **elude to it not working**, but nothing concrete.

Comment: Go to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) then click on "other versions" or [google](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2009/Nov/07/ClientIDMode-in-ASPNET-40).

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I've gotten so used to that housing every single version I thought it was broken -LOL! Thanks a lot friend!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Client ID Mode is new in ASP.NET 4.0. There's more information about it in the [breaking changes](http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/aspnet4/breaking-changes#0.1__Toc256770142) for ASP.NET v4.0.

Comment: OK, so let me ask you this, how consistent is that name going to be for this form?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud not consistent enough to be safe between major versions of ASP.NET. I learned that the hard way going from ASP.NET 1.1 to 2.0. Most of the IDs were rendered differently, so they may do that again in the future.

Comment: OK, I'll probably just have to leverage a class then. Thanks!